# Eclipse crash on Swing Application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a Swing application to view JSON structures during the debug/development phase of a larger application. The approach is simple - (1) Walk through the JSON tree in a depth first mode (b) For each node, create a corresponding DefaultMutableTreeNode (c) Stick these nodes into a JTree, and (d) put the JTree in a JScrollPane. Works fine for JSON file/String upto a few KB in size.

The problem: When used on a JSON files a few 100's of KB in size, I get the GUI on the screen alright, but after that, Eclipse crashes with the following message. I suspect the cause is the way I am creating the GUI. This is with Eclipse Neon, with Java 8 running on MacOS 10.14.6. I tried a modification - use a createGUI() method from inside the Swing invokeLater thread (comment in the commented out lines in the code for this), but the results are the same.

Can someone help with the correct mechanism to use the SwingWorker thread? I have not used Swing for a long, long time and might be missing some of the more recent developments. Another source of confusion is that I can export the project from eclipse to create an executable jar, and when invoked from the command line (shell prompt), the application works fine.

Source code is attached next. To put it in your own IDE and run it, the only external library required is "java-json.jar". Thank you for your help.

> Process:               eclipse [50201] Path:
>   /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse Identifier:
>   org.eclipse.platform.ide Version:               4.6.0
>   (4.6.0.I20160606-1100) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent
>   Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           eclipse [50201] User
>   ID:               1117050623
>
> Date/Time:             2019-10-06 11:19:55.970 -0700 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95) Report Version:        12 Bridge OS Version: 
>   3.6 (16P6571) Anonymous UUID:        44A65B77-4733-DCB5-94D3-A96597022662
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       0653A25E-D236-44CF-86ED-DB63F08A987A
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 560000 seconds Time Since Wake:       1900
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000018e40cf7b Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> VM Regions Near 0x18e40cf7b:
>       MALLOC_TINY            000000018e100000-000000018e400000 [ 3072K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
>   --> 
>       mapped file            000000018e464000-000000018e46c000 [   32K] r--/r-x SM=PRV  Object_id=3fca339b
>
> Application Specific Information: CGBlt_copyBytes: buffer check:
>   abort() called
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff607b82c6 __pthread_kill + 10
>   1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff60873bf1 pthread_kill +
>   284 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff607226a6 abort + 127
>   3   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108460181 os::abort(bool)
>   + 25 4   libjvm.dylib                     0x000000010858479e VMError::report_and_die() + 2304 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108461dfe JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010845e00b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47 7
>   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x00007fff60868b5d _sigtramp + 29 8
>   ???                               0x00007fff8906e670 sp3_gfx10_a_operand
>   + 818512 9   com.apple.CoreGraphics           0x00007fff34b95391 CGBlt_copyBytes + 385 10  com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff34b722b4 argb32_image + 5324 11  com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff34b70ddf ripl_Mark + 22 12  com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff34b70db4 RIPLayerBltImage + 1018 13  com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff34b706f6 ripc_RenderImage + 228 14  com.apple.CoreGraphics 
>     0x00007fff34b64371 ripc_DrawImage + 812 15  com.apple.CoreGraphics
>     0x00007fff34b64036 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 41 16 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff31f25397
>   __backing_store_DrawImage_block_invoke + 55 17  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff31f24260 backing_store_delegate + 893 18  com.apple.AppKit 
>     0x00007fff32240665 backing_store_DrawImage.llvm.2329424099933660171 +
>   509 19  com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff34b64036
>   CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 41 20  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff322414e6
>   backing_store_DrawWindowContents.llvm.2329424099933660171 + 1075 21 
>   com.apple.CoreGraphics            0x00007fff34be1e52
>   CGContextDelegateDrawWindowContents + 59 22  com.apple.SkyLight
>     0x00007fff59a64507 SLContextCopyWindowContentsToRect + 163 23 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff32153858 _NXScroll + 1463 24 
>   libswt-pi-cocoa-4623.jnilib       0x0000000159937139
>   Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_NSCopyBits + 187 25  ???
>     0x0000000120018427 0 + 4831937575 26  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 27  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 28  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 29  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 30  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 31  ???
>     0x0000000120008042 0 + 4831871042 32  ???
>     0x0000000120008042 0 + 4831871042 33  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 34  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 35  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 36  ???
>     0x0000000120008042 0 + 4831871042 37  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 38  ???
>     0x0000000120a39674 0 + 4842559092 39  ???
>     0x0000000120008042 0 + 4831871042 40  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 41  ???
>     0x0000000120007e54 0 + 4831870548 42  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 43  ???
>     0x0000000120008042 0 + 4831871042 44  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 45  ???
>     0x0000000120007a40 0 + 4831869504 46  ???
>     0x0000000120007a40 0 + 4831869504 47  ???
>     0x0000000120007e54 0 + 4831870548 48  ???
>     0x0000000120007e54 0 + 4831870548 49  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 50  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 51  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 52  ???
>     0x00000001200004e7 0 + 4831839463 53  libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001082e255a JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*,
>   JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710 54  libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001084a80c4 Reflection::invoke(instanceKlassHandle,
>   methodHandle, Handle, bool, objArrayHandle, BasicType, objArrayHandle,
>   bool, Thread*) + 3602 55  libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001084a85f8 Reflection::invoke_method(oopDesc*, Handle,
>   objArrayHandle, Thread*) + 364 56  libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010831de40 JVM_InvokeMethod + 358 57  ???
>     0x0000000120018427 0 + 4831937575 58  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 59  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 60  ???
>     0x0000000120007e54 0 + 4831870548 61  ???
>     0x0000000120007d80 0 + 4831870336 62  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 63  ???
>     0x0000000120007ffd 0 + 4831870973 64  ???
>     0x00000001200004e7 0 + 4831839463 65  libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001082e255a JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*,
>   JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710 66  libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001082fcf6a jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*,
>   _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) + 748 67  libjvm.dylib                     0x00000001082ee5e2
>   jni_CallIntMethod + 363 68  eclipse_1615.so
>     0x0000000100586bb2 startJavaJNI + 2138 69  eclipse_1615.so
>     0x0000000100585597 startJavaVM + 9 70  eclipse_1615.so
>     0x00000001005835a5 _run + 4196 71  eclipse_1615.so
>     0x0000000100583f8e run + 434 72  org.eclipse.platform.ide
>     0x00000001000017d2 original_main + 1819 73  org.eclipse.platform.ide 
>     0x0000000100001da4 main + 1230 74  org.eclipse.platform.ide
>     0x0000000100000f28 start + 52
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff607b586a
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff6087456e _pthread_cond_wait + 722 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010845c75a os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010843a776 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 4   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010843b05a Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 5
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x000000010843b2d2 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 390 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108598b8b GangWorker::loop() + 179 7   libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001084609ea java_start(Thread*) + 246 8
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff608712eb _pthread_body + 126
>   9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff60874249 _pthread_start +
>   66 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff6087040d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff607b586a
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff6087456e _pthread_cond_wait + 722 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010845c75a os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010843a776 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 4   libjvm.dylib
>     0x000000010843b05a Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 5
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x000000010843b2d2 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 390 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108598b8b GangWorker::loop() + 179 7   libjvm.dylib
>     0x00000001084609ea java_start(Thread*) + 246 8
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff608712eb _pthread_body + 126
>   9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff60874249 _pthread_start +
>   66 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff6087040d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 3: ...

```
package com.efe.fqa;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonView extends JSplitPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0xEFECAFE2BL;
    private JSONObject job;
    private String rootName;

    public JsonView (String title, String jsonAsString) throws JSONException {
        this (title, new JSONObject(jsonAsString));
    }

    public JsonView (String rootNodeName, JSONObject job)  throws JSONException {
        super (HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        rootName = rootNodeName;
        this.job = job;
//  }
//  
//  public void createGUI () throws JSONException {
        add (getTextPane (job), LEFT);
        add (getTreePane (rootName, job), RIGHT);
    }

    private JScrollPane getTextPane (JSONObject job) throws JSONException {
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(job.toString(4));
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane (ta);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720,400));
        return sp;
    }

    private JScrollPane getTreePane (String title, JSONObject job) throws JSONException {
        int n = job.length();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode jsonRoot=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(title + " (" + n + ")");
        expandUnitTree (jsonRoot, job);
        JTree jsonTree = new JTree(jsonRoot);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane (jsonTree);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720,400));
        return sp;
    }

    private void expandArrayTree (DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, JSONArray jarray) throws JSONException {
        int n = jarray.length();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("[" + i + "]");
            Object child = jarray.get(i);
            System.out.println ("Child class: " + child.getClass().getName());
            if (child instanceof JSONArray) {
                expandArrayTree(jsonNode, jarray.getJSONArray(i));
            } else if (child instanceof JSONObject) {
                expandUnitTree(jsonNode, jarray.getJSONObject(i));
            } else if (child instanceof String) {
                jsonNode.add (new DefaultMutableTreeNode ("\"" + child + "\""));
            } else {
                jsonNode.add (new DefaultMutableTreeNode (child.toString()));
            }
            parent.add(jsonNode);
        }
    }

    private void expandUnitTree (DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, JSONObject job) throws JSONException {
        //JSONArray names = job.names();
        //System.out.println ("[expandUnitTree] names has " + names.length() + " elements");
        //for (int i = 0 ; i < names.length() ; i++)
        System.out.println (job);
        Iterator<?> keys = job.keys();
        List<String> jobKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            jobKeys.add(keys.next().toString());
            //System.out.println (keys.next());
        }
        Collections.sort(jobKeys);
        for (String jsonKey : jobKeys) {
            Object child = job.get(jsonKey);
            Class<?> cls = child.getClass();
            System.out.println ("\t" + jsonKey + " -> " + cls.getName());
            DefaultMutableTreeNode jsonNode = null;
            if (job.isNull(jsonKey)) {
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" : null");
            } else if (child instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray jsonChild = job.getJSONArray(jsonKey);
                int n = jsonChild.length();
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" [" + n + "]");
                expandArrayTree (jsonNode, jsonChild);
            } else if (child instanceof JSONObject) {
                JSONObject jsonChild = job.getJSONObject(jsonKey);
                int n = jsonChild.length();
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" (" + n + ")");
                expandUnitTree (jsonNode, jsonChild);
            } else if (child instanceof Boolean) {
                boolean bool = job.getBoolean(jsonKey);
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" : " + bool);
            } else if (child instanceof Integer) {
                int iNumber = job.getInt(jsonKey);
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" : " + iNumber); 
            } else if (child instanceof Double) {
                double dNumber = job.getDouble(jsonKey);
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" : " + dNumber);
            } else {
                String str = job.getString(jsonKey);
                jsonNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("\"" + jsonKey + "\" : \"" + str + "\"");
            }
            parent.add(jsonNode);
        }
    }

    public static JSONObject readJsonFile (File file) throws IOException, JSONException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file));
        for (String s = br.readLine() ; s != null ; s = br.readLine())
            sb.append(s);
        br.close();
        return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        if (fc.showOpenDialog(new JFrame()) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                JSONObject job = readJsonFile (file);
                String fileName = file.getName();
                JFrame fr = new JFrame ("JsonView: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                JsonView jv = new JsonView ("[JsonView] File: " + fileName, job);
                fr.getContentPane().add(jv);
                fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
//                      try {
//                          jv.createGUI();
                            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                            int height = screenSize.height;
                            int width = screenSize.width;
                            fr.pack();
                            Dimension pfSize = fr.getSize();
                            fr.setLocation((width - pfSize.width)/2, (height - pfSize.height)/2 - 200);
                            fr.setVisible(true);
//                      } catch (JSONException jex) {
//                          jex.printStackTrace();
//                      }
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can someone help with the correct mechanism to use the SwingWorker thread?" -- what SwingWorker? I don't see any of your SwingWorker code within your question's code-post.

Comment: I am not sure if it is needed (or how/why to use it), hence the question. I will be happy if this code runs without any additional threads without crashing Eclipse.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the crux of your question appears to be about creating a SwingWorker that helps avoid this crash, but since this is not a site for creating code for you, it would seem to be best to work from your own attempt, no?

Comment: Possibly [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502711) Eclipse bug which was fixed some time ago. Eclipse Neon is now 7 releases out of date

Comment: @Hovercraft: Would you know why this code is crashing Eclipse in the first place, when it runs fine at the command line? Then we can discuss how/if we need a SwingWorker or something else. I believe this site is meant for coders to help each other, and I am not asking anybody to write my code for me.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you, that makes sense. I will try a more recent Eclipse version.

Comment: It's not really a "help site" per se but rather a Q/A site, a subtle difference but key. Hopefully updating your Eclipse fixes the problem. Else, you may wish to do more trouble-shooting.

Comment: Please do let us know if updating Eclipse solves the problem.

Comment: On 2nd thoughts, I am thinking about coding in the lines of "if (running_in_eclipse) do_not_show_GUI" ... I already have the JSON in the logs, was trying to make my life easier in short-circuiting the "copy-from-log and paste to a json-editor in some web-browser tab", because large contents make this copy-paste work very tedious.

Comment: @Hovercraft I tried a recent version of Eclipse, and the code worked, without Eclipse crashing. Unfortunately, I am stuck in a development environment with a fixed version of Eclipse - so while my code works on a different version, I need to find a workaround to continue using the buggy version :(